# How to show date in java in a specific sequence

Tags: java, date

I wrote a code he give me a list of dates between two dates

Start date 1.1.2014

End date 5.1.2014

Output

1.1.2014

2.1.2014

3.1.2014

4.1.2014

5.1.2014

But what I need Is that the list of dates show me a list of dates between two dates where 4 days on . 2 days off

So the list between

Start date 1.1.2014 and End date 12.1.2014

Will be

1.1.2014

2.1.2014

3.1.2014

4.1.2014

7.1.2014

8.1.2014

9.1.2014

10.1.2014

RESULT: on the date 12.1.2014 you are off

This my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{

    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type the start date like this d.m.y");
    String str_date = scn.next();
    System.out.println("Type the end date like this d.m.y");
    String end_date = scn.next();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    Date  startDate = formatter.parse(str_date); 
    Date  endDate = formatter.parse(end_date);
    long interval = 24*1000 * 60 * 60;
    long endTime =endDate.getTime() ;
    long curTime = startDate.getTime();
    while (curTime <= endTime) {
        dates.add(new Date(curTime));
        curTime += interval;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<dates.size();i++){
        Date lDate =dates.get(i);
        String ds = formatter.format(lDate);    
        System.out.println(ds);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the requirement "where 4 days on . 2 days off". Could you please explain it more precisely?

Comment: my work days is 4 days on 2 days off so I want to do such thing so I will know after 2 months for example if I'm off or not

Comment: I still cannot see any sense in this sentence, especially when seeing the date you list you expect. This list is simply missing the 9.11.2014 and the 11.11.2014. In regard to that list, what does "4 days on 2 days off" mean?

Comment: If I have mon tue wed thu work then fri sat off then sun mon tue wed work then thu fri off

Comment: But that also means, that your expected list is wrong. Please edit your question, so that your requirements become clear.

Comment: Your question and/or the test data still does not make sense. One completely different issue with your code is however that you assume there to be 86400000 ms in one day.

Comment: Sorry I edited my quesrion please review the dates list

Comment: If you only care about date without time-of-day, use the `LocalDate` class in either Joda-Time or java.time (Java 8). Both offer a `plusDays` method.

Comment: Thank you Basil Bourque I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (curTime <= endTime) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 4 && curTime <= endTime; ++k) {
        dates.add(new Date(curTime));
        curTime += interval;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < 2 && curTime <= endTime; ++k) {
        curTime += interval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great man thank you so much. Now could you help me with the last part the message. At that date you are off or at that date you are on

Comment: Well, it's on if it's in the dates list isn't it?